# jPlayer play event is not firing when audio start playing automatically

Tags: events, jplayer

I got a problem with jPlayer.

When the page loaded, the player plays automatically but it doesn't trigger "play" event.

Only when I click on pause button and click on play button again, the event is triggered.

Is that a bug of jPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

hard to say since you don't mention which browser you are experiencing this in but my experience is that it is safer to rely on the 'playing' event rather than the 'play' event. Ideally the 'play' event is to be fired as soon as you call jPlayer('play') and 'playing' then is fired once the actual playback starts (i.e. after initial buffering etc). What I've seen this works fine in Safari but does not work in Chrome, in Chrome the two events are both fired when content starts to play.